# java swing - How to draw Rects one on top of the next using?

Tags: java, swing

Using java swing, I have a horizontal line (acting as the horizon). I want to draw rects, stacked, one on top of the other where the rect with the largest width is at the bottom and the rect with the smallest width is at the top. I also want the rects to stick to the horizon when the user re-sizes the screen. this is the calculation i have so far:

```
package testing;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test extends JFrame {
    private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 600;
    private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 500;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }
    
    protected Test() {
        this.setTitle("Tower of Hanoi");
        this.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT));
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT));
        this.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT));
        this.setSize(new Dimension(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT));
        this.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        this.add(new PanelTest(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public class PanelTest extends JPanel {

        private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 600;
        private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 500;
         
        protected PanelTest() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            this.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
            this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT));
            this.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT));
            this.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
            this.add(new ComponentTest(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
            revalidate();
            repaint();
            this.setVisible(true); //probably not necessary

        }
    }
    
    public class ComponentTest extends JComponent {
        private List<Rectangle> rects; 
        
        public ComponentTest() {
            rects = new ArrayList<>(); 
            rects.add(new Rectangle(30, 30, 30, 30));
            rects.add(new Rectangle(30, 30, 30, 30));
            rects.add(new Rectangle(30, 30, 30, 30));
            rects.add(new Rectangle(30, 30, 30, 30));
        }
        
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            Graphics2D graph2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            graph2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            
            paint(g);
        }
        
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            // Draw the platform
            g.drawLine(100, getHeight() - 100, getWidth() - 100, getHeight() - 100);
                        
            for(int i = 0; i < rects.size(); i++) {
                rects.get(i).setBounds(getWidth()/2,
                        (30 * i + 1),
                        30 * i + 1,
                        30
                        );
                g.drawRect(rects.get(i).x, rects.get(i).y, rects.get(i).width, rects.get(i).height);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this leaves the rects stacked but floating near the top of the screen:
[image]

how do i get it to stick to the black horizon line? in other words, how do i get the largest rect to rest on top of the black line? furthermore, when the screen is dragged to be a larger size - how can i grow all of the rects heights (equally) and have it still stuck to the black horizon?

also note, the number of rects being drawn is decided by the user (in this example it's 5, but it could be anything up to 9).

**Update**
doing this also does not work as expected:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < rects.size(); i++) {
        rects.get(i).setBounds(getWidth()/2,
                (30 * i + 1),
                getHeight() - 100 - (30 * (rects.size() - (i + 1))),
                30
                );
        g.drawRect(rects.get(i).x, rects.get(i).y, rects.get(i).width, rects.get(i).height);
    }
```

Comment: Please add additional context - what graphics library are you using?  What is the totalDiskHeight variable? is d.getNumber the number of the rectangle you are drawing?

Comment: @ToreHanssen sorry, i've clarified.

Comment: @Abra i have updated the question with the minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @ToreHanssen i have updated the question with a minimal example that can be tried out. doing `getHeight() - 100 - (30 * (count(rects) - d.getNumber()))` did not seem to solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need class `ComponentTest`. You only need class `PanelTest` and you only need to override method `paintComponent()` in class `PanelTest`. Refer to [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/).

If you fix the location of the *horizon* in `PanelTest` then you need to draw the rectangles relative to the *horizon*. The `x` coordinate is the same for each rectangle as is the height, so you just need to calculate the width (which you are already doing correctly) and the `y` coordinate.

This means that the `y` coordinate for the bottom-most rectangle, i.e. the one touching the *horizon*, needs to be the `y` coordinate of the *horizon* minus the height of the rectangle.

The `y` coordinate of the rectangle directly above the bottom-most rectangle needs to be the `y` coordinate of the *horizon* minus twice the height of the rectangle, since each rectangle has the same height.

And so on for the remaining rectangles.

Here is my rewrite of class `PanelTest`. As I said, no need for class `ComponentTest` and I made no changes to class `Test`.

Note that since you are drawing rectangles, using anti-aliasing makes no difference. It makes a difference when you draw curved shapes or diagonal lines. There is also no need for class `Graphics2D` since you don't use any of that class's methods.

```java
public class PanelTest extends JPanel {
    private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 600;
    private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 500;

    private List<Rectangle> rects;

    protected PanelTest() {
        rects = new ArrayList<>();
        rects.add(new Rectangle(30, 30, 30, 30));
        rects.add(new Rectangle(30, 30, 30, 30));
        rects.add(new Rectangle(30, 30, 30, 30));
        rects.add(new Rectangle(30, 30, 30, 30));
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT));
        this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT));
        this.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT));
        this.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.drawLine(100, getHeight() - 100, getWidth() - 100, getHeight() - 100);

        for (int i = 0; i < rects.size(); i++) {
            rects.get(i).x = getWidth() / 2;
            rects.get(i).y = getHeight() - 100 - (30 * (rects.size() - i));
            rects.get(i).width = 30 * i + 1;
            rects.get(i).height = 30;
            g.drawRect(rects.get(i).x, rects.get(i).y, rects.get(i).width, rects.get(i).height);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So if each bar has a height of 30, then this is the pixel height each rect needs to start at:

1. getHeight() - 100 - (30 * count(rects))
2. getHeight() - 100 - (30 * (count(rects) - 1))
   ...
3. getHeight() - 100 - (30 * (count(rects) - 4))

So, for the Nth rectangle, `getHeight() - 100 - (30 * (count(rects) - d.getNumber()))`

I'm not sure if this will work when resized - but you might have to plug into the right lifecycle events in order to get that to work.  As mentioned in a comment above, a minimally reproducible example would make it possible to help more

Comment: hmm this doesn't seem to work - please see my update. thanks for the suggestion though.